# Make element fixed of static after scroll and dynamic height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fixed

I have a footer area, that should be always visible on the bottom of the page. But, if there is not enought height above it, it should stick under ( static/relative ).
I've come up with this very basic code:

```
if( footer.offset().top < sidebarContents.innerHeight() ) {
    footer.addClass('static');
}
else {
    footer.removeClass('static');
}
```

And this is wrapped in $(window).scroll().

The problem is, the footer flickers when on, or below the proper height. It jumps from fixed to static with every scroll change. I know, that the if is somehow wrong.

Can anyone give me some advice on how to handle it, please?

Comment: Are you checking to see if footer has the class before removing it or adding it?

Comment: Yes, added check to determine if there if class before removing, and  if not, before adding, not the solution.

Comment: Can you post a sample on http://jsfiddle.net to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I've abandoned the idea, making slightly other feature. But thanks for Your will to help.